# Unsafe raw pointer from weak_ptr - safety guaranteed by context

Tags: shared-ptr, weak-references

I am storing a `weak_ptr` for avoiding circular structure, and I know that in some particular context the `shared_ptr` is still valid.

Can I get the raw pointer from `weak_ptr` without casting to `shared_ptr` (which involves memory write)?

(note: this is not a duplicate of [How to maintain a weak pointer to a parent in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056254), I am specifically asking about an unsafe way, not about getting the pointer as such)

Answer (score 0):

> Can I get the raw pointer from weak_ptr without casting to shared_ptr

No.

N.B. you don't "cast" you construct a `shared_ptr` from the `weak_ptr`.

> (which involves memory write)?

What do you mean here?  Creating a `shared_ptr` will increment a reference count, is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly the reference count increment. If I use the pointer only briefly and know it is valid, that is useless.

Comment: PS sorry for the `cast` wording, I know it means constructing a `shared_ptr`.